# YQL for historical between currencies beside USD

Tags: java, yql

I'm trying to get historical currencies but not necessarly relative to USD, using YQL queries.

For instance, this would work nice

> select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "BWP=X" and
>   startDate = "2009-01-01" and endDate = "2009-02-01"

but throws currency between BWP and USD... i would need BWP/EUR

If I try:

> select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("BWPEUR")

it gives a single result, but not historical...

i've been searching and trying combinations, but no result or null result. Is there a way?

Thanks a lot

Comment: same issue, any progress?